# MYSQL query into Laravel Eloquent ORM

Tags: mysql, laravel

Hey I am new using laravel and I have some problems when I have to make some querys with the eloquent ORM.

I have this tables: Internship , Student and internship_student(attendance).

My pivot table has an attendance attribute (absent or present) and I need the ID of the internship and count the students that are present for each internship.

I have the raw query but i want to learn how i can do it with the tools that laravel provide.

Here is my raw query:

```
DB::table('internship_student')
        ->select(DB::raw('count(*) as real_assistants, internship_id'))
        ->where('attendance', '=', 1)
        ->groupBy('internship_id')
        ->get();
```

Comment: I do not see any problem with your code. You can use more function of [Laravel eloquent](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent) and [Laravel Query Builder](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/queries#introduction). In order to check you query, before using `get()` method, you use `->toSql()` to get your query string and check that query is OK or not. (If you had parametters, replaced `?` to your value before executing your query)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on your query, I'm guessing you have a `Many to Many` relationship between `Internship` and `Student`. Based on this, your models should look as follows

**Internship Model**:

```
public function students() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Student')->withPivot('attendance');
}
```

**Student Model**:

```
public function internships() {
  return $this->belongsToMany('App\Internship')->withPivot('attendance');
}
```

With this, you **should** be able to call with Eloquent Models:

```
count($internship->students()->where('attendance', '=', 1)->get());
```

OR using a Mutator you could create a custom attribute to get the count of attendance:

```
public function getRealAssistantsAttribute() {
   return $this->students()->where('attendance', '=', 1)->get();
}

//On an Internship instance
count($internship->real_assistants);
```

**EDIT**:

One final way using Eager Loading would be something like this:

```
$internships = Internship::withCount([
  'students as real_attendants' => function($query) {
     $query->where('attendance', '=', 1);
  }
])->get();
```

You can then access it using:

```
$internships[0]->real_attendants_count;
```

Comment: Thanks, the last one was the one that I needed

Comment: @Enjoyer if so, please mark this as the correct answer :)